# Delete a database record along with its related records

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a database of products, categories and "productsInCategories" looking something like:

---

**Users**

```
id█  name  ▌
▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▌
1 █  john  ▌
69█  jane  ▌
```

---

**Products**

```
id█  name  █ cost █description▌
▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▌
21█snickers█  23  █ foo       ▌
34█  mars  █  20  █ bar       ▌
37█  daim  █  21  █ oofrab    ▌
79█ banana █  8   █ foobar    ▌
80█  apple █  10  █ barfoo    ▌
```

---

**Categories**

```
id█  userId █   name  ▌
▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▌
10█    69   █chocolate▌
55█    69   █favorites▌
20█    1    █ fruit   ▌
```

---

**ProductsInCategories**

```
categoryId█productId▌
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▌
    10    █   21    ▌
    10    █   34    ▌
    20    █   79    ▌
    20    █   80    ▌
    55    █   21    ▌
    55    █   37    ▌
```

---

This produces something that could be looked upon as:

```
Users
   john
      fruit
         banana
         apple
   jane
      chocolate
         snickers
         mars
         daim
      favorites
         snickers
         daim
```

When I want to get all the producuts of a category I do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
        INNER JOIN ProductsInCategories
        ON Products.Id=ProductsInCategories.product
        WHERE category=@0
,@0=categoryId
```

That's all working fine and inserting or deleting products is pretty straight forward.
However I now have a problem I can't wrap my head around.

Namely **deleting categories**. How would I go on about doing that? I have been working on it for hours but can't seem to get it working.
If a user deletes a category I want all products that exists *only* in that category to get deleted along with the associated productInCategories-records.
If say user "Jane" deletes her category "chocolate" then I want to delete the product "mars" but not "snickers" or "mars" because they also exist in the category "favorites"

Comment: Since your main question is about deleting, not joining, I would adapt the title accordingly.

Comment: You're fast. I changed it in like 5 seconds after i posted the question. The title was actually from another question which I solved myself after having started to write the question.

Comment: With so many users on stackoverflow someone is bound to be 'fast', i.e. the first one seeing your question.

Comment: Certainly. Didn't mean to criticize you or anything for pointing it out quickly =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pseodocode to get you going:

```
 Delete from ProductsIncategories where category = X

 Delete from products where productID in (
    select productID from
        products left outer join productsincategories 
        on products.productID = productsincategories.productID
    where 
        productsincategories.categoryid is null
 )

 delete from categories where category = x
```

1. if you remove the products in categories first as is depends on other tables and nothing depends on it.
2. look for product now in no categories - these are the ones that were only  in the         category to be removed - this is done by left outer joining from product to productsincategories - this gives all rows from products and null if they have no matching record from products in categories
3. remove the category itself as nothing is now linked to it.

As a side note consider not removing the products only in this category and instead give a report of these for people to review and clean up. seems to me work might be lost too often otherwise.  maybe at least give them the chance to confirm before you delete them

Also note that the middle statement is going to remove EVERY product not in a category.. thre are two schools of thought on issues like this

1. any product not in a category is a mistake so clean them all up when ever you can
2. there are all kinds of reasons why a product may have no category this is no use to me!

if you want to only remove products that were only in this category and a blanket remove is not good then something like this might help:

```
select productID form
from
    products as p
    inner join productsincategories as pic
        on PIC.productid = p.productid
    inner join (
        select distinct productID from productsincategories 
        where categoryid = X
    ) as t
        on t.productid = p.productid
 group by 
    productid
 having 
    count(*) = 1
```

here is that select in action using Joachim Isaksson's fiddle (+1'ing your answer now Joachim)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a744/22

LEFT OUTER JOINS - quick notes

```
table a
id
1
2


table b
aID   value
1     x
1     y


a left outer join b (select * from a left outer join b on a.id = b.aID)
id  aID value
1   1   x
1   1   y
2   NULLNULL

b left outer join a (select * from b left outer join a on a.id = b.aID)
aID value id
1   x     1
1   y     1
```

left outer join gives you everything from the table on the left and matches from the table on the right.  where there is a row in the left table and not in the right you get NULL for all columns of the table on the right.  hope that helps but well worth a googling and experimentation to get comfortable with.

Its very useful when you want to say looks at sales for all items but you want to have the item list whether there are sales or not. Or like we have used it here to find everything that is in one table not in another by only selecting where the "right" table is null

Comment: You got a typo 'onroducts.productID`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's really appreciated. Still trying to understand all of it. I've never used left outer joining.
And yeah, the plan was to let the user get a warning when deleting a category, which also lists the products that exists only in that category and therefore would be deleted. But yeah, might do some changing on that. I'll get back after having tried this code.

Comment: no worries.. note Joachim Isaksson's answer for neater use of delete syntax and fiddle example

Comment: For now I'm using your first code and it's working nicely, though I don't wholly understand it yet. Guess I should read up a bit on that so I don't use things I don't get. I didn't get Joachim Isaksson's statement working but I guess that's something about SQLCE.

Comment: might well be SQLCE syntax thing, which bit is that you are not sure of? maybe `in` or the use of `left outer join`?

Comment: @Clox guess it was left outer joining - written a crappy explanation there.. probably better off googling it ;)

Comment: Ahh, and those left outer joins are on a.id=b.aID? Makes sense! Didn't even have to google =)

Comment: @Clox Yup sorry didn't write that explicitly but you got it anyways ;)

Answer (score 5):

Unless you set up cascading deletes in the schema, you need to use 3 delete statements, one for each table.

```
-- Delete category 10 from Categories table.
DELETE FROM Categories WHERE Id=10;

-- Delete category 10 from ProductsInCategories table.
DELETE FROM ProductsInCategories WHERE CategoryId=10;

-- Delete all products that are no longer in a category    
DELETE Products
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN ProductsInCategories
  ON ProductId=Products.Id
WHERE ProductId IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a744/16).

Comment: Ahh, so simple! Thanks! I don't know that much about cascading deletes. I've only googled and read about it but never used it. Should one of these be preferred over the other in this case? Could one be better in performance?

Comment: IMHO they are the preferred way since they ensure the integrity of your data as part of the foreign key.

Comment: @Clox As inflagranti says, cascading deletes are the preferred way to keep consistency, and it will give a _slight_ performance advantage as compared to 3 round trips to the database. It's a bit of a science to set up correctly, but analysing the relations almost always gives some extra insight due to the decisions you have to make.

Comment: Alright. I'm trying out your code now but I get a parsing-error for that third query, the one for deleting products that don't belong to any category. "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 6,Token in error = FROM ]" I tried changing the two first lines to "DELETE FROM Products" but then I get this error instead: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 6,Token in error = LEFT ]". Could this be some limitation of SQLCE?

Comment: I got gordatron's statement for deleting categoryless products working. Bet its something about SQLCE...

Comment: @Clox Most likely, I don't have CE to test on.